# Can't use Python dict in Django template tag

Tags: python, django

I checked multiple posts and solutions but can't make it happen.

I have a Python object returned within a view. I now want to use data from that dict to render it using Django template tags.

Somehow nothing shows up though...

**View:**

```
def render_Terminal(request, template="Terminal.html"):
    account_information = AccountInformation.objects.all()
    account_information_dict = {
        'account_information': account_information
    }
    return render(request, template, (account_information_dict))
```

**HTML**

```
     <div id="oneTwo" class="columnsOne">
       {{ account_information.pk }}
     </div>
```

**Using just `account_information` within the tag, I get:**

```
<QuerySet [<AccountInformation: AccountInformation object (30e61aec-0f6e-4fa0-8c1b-eb07f9347c1f)>]>
```

Where is the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AccountInformation.objects.all()` is a `QuerySet` with a `all()` filter. A QuerySet is iterable, and it executes its database query the first time you iterate over it. You can show the id for all items in your list using:

```html
{% for item in account_information %}
  <div id="some-id-{{ forloop.counter }}" class="some-class">
     {{ item.pk }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do like this

```
def render_Terminal(request, template="Terminal.html"):
    account_information = AccountInformation.objects.all()
    account_information_dict = {
        'account_information': [a for a in account_information]
    }
    return render(request, template, (account_information_dict))
```

and

```
<div id="oneTwo" class="columnsOne">
   {{ account_information.0.pk }}
</div>
```

however you can only recover the first item that comes

---

a better solution might be

```
account_information = AccountInformation.objects.get(pk=`you id`)
return render(request, template, (account_information_dict))
```

and then

```
<div id="oneTwo" class="columnsOne">
   {{ account_information.pk }}
</div>
```

---

`Using just account_information within the tag, I get:`

inside the html code you have to put the item in "for" if you take the integer value

```
 {% for a in account_information %}
      <div>
            {{ a.pk }}
      </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Works, thank you + upvoted, although the other answer is a bit more extensive, thats why I accept this one.

Comment: I am looking for help but I do not know what may be the reason for its use, so above have some options and hope you understand how django works to have the best use and if you have any questions feel free to ask.